# Error : no operator " != " matches these operands

Tags: c++, casting

When instead of `operator !=`, `<<` is considered, such error can be removed by including `<string>` header.

But this doesn't seem to work on `operator !=`.

So, I thought may be this error is due to difference in type of the variables I'm comparing.

So I considered type casting.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
while ( (cin >> value) != 0) { ... }
```

The type of value is `int`.

Some options that I considered are:

1. Static cast : can't be used because we are accepting value at run time.
2. Dynamic cast : can't use since `value` isn't a pointer
3. `reinterpret_cast` : same

What other options do I have?

You can suggest some alternatives as well but I would like to know how to make it work.

Comment: First and foremost: what are you trying to achieve by this comparison? Why are you comparing a stream to zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resultant value of `(cin >> value)` is not the contents of `value`, but rather `cin`. `cin` can be evaluated in a boolean context but doesn't compare to the `int`, hence the compilation error.

You can modify the line to be (using the comma operator);

```
while ( (cin >> value, value) != 0)
```

The resultant here is the second operand of the comma operator, hence the `value`. In turn it will compare with the `0` correctly. Although this now forgoes the validity tests on the `cin` stream.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3e04ee0611538b6).

Whilst a minimal change is presented above, the code itself tends to be obscure and misses some error checking. It is better to refactor the condition and provide more checks for errors in `cin`;

```
while ( (cin >> value) && (value != 0) ) {
  //...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb3308619cb13f26).

Comment: Plus one: love the use of the comma operator. Sadly though the current crop of code reviewers who learnt C++ in the gutter may not allow it.

Comment: @Bathsheba sadly version with comma does not do any error checking. It would work properly in C++11 and later, but not earlier. You would have to enable exceptions for `cin` or risk infinite loop.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot. Correct. I presented it as a minimal change to get the compile to work, and a solution with more error checking as well. Not checking the validity of your stream is just asking for problems...

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function `foo` (taking `cin` by reference), that essentially contains

```
cin >> value;
return value;
```

and write `while ((value = foo(cin)) != 0){...}`. `foo` could exploit the exception mechanism to report any errors in the reading. You could even replace `foo` with a *lambda* function But really, this rather obfuscates things. Just accept that `cin >> value` is an *expression* with a stream type, and work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your `while` loop as a `for` loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int value;
    for( std::cin >> value; value != 0; std::cin >> value) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/993bdccfe735a6ae)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If the expression `cin >> value` evaluated to `value` you wouldn't be able to do this:

```
cin >> v1 >> v2
```

Remember that `cin >> value` is equivalent to

```
cin.operator>>(value);
```

A quick look at [`std::istream::operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) tells us that it returns a `std::istream&`. So `cin >> v1 >> v2` is

```
cin.operator>>(v1).operator>>(v2);
```

or

```
istream& is = cin.operator>>(v1);
is.operator>>(v2);
```

Your code:

```
(cin >> value) != 0
```

is

```
istream& is = cin.operator>>(value);
if (is != 0)  // error: comparing `istream` and `int`.
```

You could perhaps write:

```
while (cin >> value, value != 0) {
```

this evaluates `cin >> value`, discards the result (i.e. `cin`) and then evaluates `value != 0`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int value;
    while (std::cin >> value, value != 0) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/bZ9PwJ

This suffers from the issue that if you get a bad input from cin you'll be permanently stuck in your loop (http://ideone.com/JtI9fp).

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int value;
    while (std::cin >> value && value != 0) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/OjI01d

This exits the loop on both a bad input and an input with a value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

`cin>>value` returns `cin`.
This provides us with the flexibility to use `cin>>val1>>val2`.
So if we use it as a condition it would act as Boolean and return `True(cin>>value).`
If you wish to use `cin` as a condition then you may use following approach..

```
int value;
while(cin>>value)
{
if(value!=0)
   cout<<"true"<<endl;
else 
   cout<<"false"<<endl;
}
```

This will give correct results. But if we use

```
    int value;
while(cin>>value!=0)
{
   cout<<"True"<<endl;
}
```

Then it will always give true as output because every time whatever the value of variable `value` be `cin>>value` returns `true`.